# Retrieving data from a Google spreadsheet in an Android app

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-api

I am developing an Android App that has to retrieve data from a Google spreadsheet. I have found posts online that suggest that I use the Google drive API but I haven't found any example on how this can be done. Can someone please help me with an example on retrieving data from a Google spreadsheet using the Google Drive API? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Drive API will only allow you to download the spreadsheet file. If you want to retrieve cell data from within a spreadsheet you must use the older spreadsheet API. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

Comment: Thanks! I got hold of the Spreadsheet API and it's working fine

Answer (score 2):

This is what I figured out on how to retrieve data from a Google Spreadsheet, with thanks also going to pinoyyid for his post. First download the gdata library from http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/downloads/list.

In order to integrate the library with your project, assuming you are using Eclipse in Windows, follow these steps:

**1.** Unzip the folder and copy the following jar files contained in the path:

```
gdata-src.java-1.47.1\gdata\java\lib and gdata-src.java-1.47.1\gdata\java\deps into the "libs" folder in your project directory:
gdata-client-1.0
gdata-client-meta-1.0
gdata-core-1.0
gdata-spreadsheet-3.0
gdata-spreadsheet-meta-3.0
guava-13.0.1
```

**2.** Once copied refresh the project in Eclipse by going to File --> Refresh. The files should now appear in `libs` in the project tree.

**3.** Expand the `libs` directory in the project tree and right click on the jars you want to include and select "add to build path".

**4.** Now follow the instructions at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

While the gdata libs will work, I'm not sure I'd suggest using them for a new project. From http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/ ...

> Warning: We have stopped actively developing this client library,
>   except critical bug fixes and support for some Google API's. However,
>   this client library is not deprecated, and is considered the "stable"
>   choice, unless you have a specific requirement that is only supported
>   by the new client library below.
>
> Android support
>
> Since GData Java Client Library does not support Android, Android
>   developers should instead use the new library Google API Client
>   Library for Java. This new library provides other important features,
>   such as OAuth 2.0 and Maven. Unfortunately, there is no provided
>   service-specific libraries for Google Data APIs, and instead you need
>   to write your own XML data model classes.